# How do I specify the interval for every decision variable? CPLEX

Tags: optimization, cplex, ilog

I have an array of decision variables that represent an amount of product. I want that each of them could be 0 (if it is not selected) or in some interval ([0.2;0.8]). forall is not working.

```
{string} Produkti = ...;
{string} Vielas = ...;

float Izmaksas[Produkti] = ...;
float vielVertibas[Produkti][Vielas]= ...;
float Normas[Vielas]= ...;
dvar float+ prodApjoms[Produkti];

minimize
    sum(p in Produkti) Izmaksas[p] * prodApjoms[p];
    
subject to{
    forall(v in Vielas) sum (p in Produkti) vielVertibas[p][v] * prodApjoms[p] >= Normas[v]*0.95;
    forall(v in Vielas) sum (p in Produkti) vielVertibas[p][v] * prodApjoms[p] <= (Normas[v]*1.05);
    sum (p in Produkti) prodApjoms[p] <= 15;
    sum (p in Produkti) prodApjoms[p] >= 5;
}
```

Comment: [AIMMS Modeling Guide - Integer Programming Tricks: Pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Mohamed_Mourad_Lafifi/post/How_can_I_model_a_production_line_in_AIMMS_with_the_aim_of_time_minimization/attachment/59d6431779197b807799ea03/AS%3A441694119305218%401482319492550/download/integer_programming_tricks_-_aimms_modeling_guide.pdf) -> 7.1 | Or in (some) Commercial-Solvers: `Semi-Continuous Variables` -> [Blog-Post about the Topic from another SO-User](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/08/semi-continuous-variables.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
forall(p in Produkti) 
    (prodApjoms[p]==0) || ((0.2<=prodApjoms[p]) && (prodApjoms[p]<=0.8));
```

will do the job

And full working example in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zoosemiinteger.mod

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 (nbBus40==0) || (4<=nbBus40<=20);
 (nbBus30==0) || (4<=nbBus30<=20);
 
 
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
} 

/*

which gives

nbBus40 = 8;
nbBus30 = 0;

*/
```